# If I use css to change a image to black and white, how would I unset that property on hover?

Tags: html, css

I am using this **CSS** to make and image black and white.

```
 img {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);
 }
```

On hover of this image, I would like to remove the styles in order to change it back to color. My attempt:

```
img:hover {
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); filter: grayscale(0%); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use](http://jsfiddle.net/47caa5jk/) `none`:

```
img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}
```